# How to replace a string in a SQL Server Table Column with the same size of text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a table (SQL Sever) with some values in it (Column name path), but now I want to update each row with a specific letter say x.

In the path column, I have many records and I need to change whatever the value in the path column with x, if a row is of 5 then the column will be replaced by xxxxx, if column is of length 9 then xxxxxxxxx to get in that place. And I need to change in every record.

How can I do this simply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update tablename
set path = REPLICATE('x', len(path))
```